# Javascript setInterval loop play audio clip out of rythm and drop sometime on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android

I tried to play very small and short mp3 (5kb, 200ms) file using javascript. I loop it using `setInterval`. I have no problem playing it on desktop browsers.

When I play on a mid-range android phone (both browser and app webview) and android emulators (Nox player, Android Studio Emulator), it skips palying sometime. And it doesn't play in exact rythm. It's delaying a few milliseconds sometimes.

When I use even smaller audio file (1kb, 100ms), it doesn't skip anymore but it is still out of rythm. My code is very simple and pleas see below. Do you have any idea? How can I optimize the code so it plays in exact timing without droppng?

```
var tap_sound = new Audio("/audio/tap2.mp3");
tap_looping_Job = setInterval(()=> {
        tap_sound.play();
    }, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going on here is a difference of execution times between platforms.

When you use `setInterval` to control playing audio, it's possible that the interval will be faster than the execution. `setInterval` could be called again before the previous sound has finished playing. This would result in the funky behavior that you're seeing.

Since the desktop has a faster CPU, you just haven't noticed it there yet.

A quick solution/test would be to increase the time of the interval until it works on mobile without any issues.

The other issue with `setInterval` is that you can tell it to wait ***400ms***, but it might actually take ***600ms*** to be called again since JavaScript is single-threaded. Your delay is more like a request to JavaScript and it will fulfill it after the specified delay, but not guaranteed to be immediate.

A better solution is to use `requestAnimationFrame` in a loop, calculate the delta time between each frame, and once the delta has reached the target, 400ms in this case, trigger the sound. Only way to get it perfect.

This website has a good explanation: [How setInterval works in JavaScript](https://bonsaiilabs.com/setInterval-javascript/)